# Is it possible to rewind a python StringIO in-memory file?

Tags: python, stringio

Let's say I have a StringIO file-like object I just created from a string. I pass it to a function which expects files. This functions reads the entire file through the end. I want to now pass it to another function which expects a file-like object. Can I rewind it so that it can be read from the beginning? If not, what other approaches can I take to accomplish this that would be most pythonic?

Comment: reset the pointer `s.seek(0)`

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

certainly: most file-like objects in python that can possibly be rewound already support [`seek()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek)

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> f = StringIO.StringIO("hello world")
>>> f.read(6)
'hello '
>>> f.tell()
6
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> f.tell()
0
>>> f.read()
'hello world'
>>>
```

Comment: This fine example has aged a bit with Python 3. Today, the first two lines should read: 
```import io
f = io.StringIO("hello world")```